# Is there any tool available to get iframe Id given on the webpage?

Tags: iframe, selenium, webdriver

It is not possible to get iFrame ID using firefox-firebug.

I want to get that iframe id i go to page source and manually search it from there.

for selenium automation under the controls of iframe

```
driver.switchTo().frame("");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there's a name or id on the `iframe`, Firebug should show it (at least in the DOM tab of the element - rightclick the element and select Inspect in DOM tab). If there's no name or id, no tool will help you getting it.

You should consider selecting the frame via

[`driver.switchTo().frame(int index)`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.TargetLocator.html#frame%28int%29)

or (my favourite)

[`driver.switchTo().frame(WebElement frameElement)`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.TargetLocator.html#frame%28org.openqa.selenium.WebElement%29)